# Setting -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios, html, mobile, css

I'm having a hard time getting the new iOS5 CSS3 property for overflow scrolling to set using jQuery.  Does jQuery support this css property?  Is there a better way to do it? I am even doing it right?

```
$("#div").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch");
```

Answer (score 0):

As with the .prop() method, the .css() method in jQuery makes setting properties of elements quick and easy. This method can take either a property name and value as separate parameters, or a single map of key-value pairs (JavaScript object notation).
Example:

```
.css(propertyName, value)
propertyName - A CSS property name.
value - A value to set for the property.
```

The problem is that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is not native CSS property, but proprietary, that`s why jQuery could not handle it correctly.
See here for details: http://api.jquery.com/css/